# Android high res photo using camera preview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

Is it possible to programmatically take a picture in full/high resolution? I use the camera preview and surface with some custom overlay content. **The problem is that the takePhoto function returns data only in preview size low resolutions**.

Even if I check the getSupportedPictureSizes the resolutions that are listed are far from the 5Mpix that is the max supported resolution by the system camera. So the question is can I take a photo in max resolution and use custom camera preview or I have to call the system camera Intent to have a full res photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you should setPictureSize(), see https://github.com/alexcohn/JBcamera for example.

**PS** Thanks, Benjamin, for drawing my attention back to this question. if I understand correctly, the author was upset with the resolution of data array returned from IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. But this is only the thumbnail; the actual hi-rez imagis writn to file. You can find this Jpeg file and load it into your app, in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 0):

By default I think it is set to a low resolution. To change this call `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your intent. See here for more detail:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE